# Saving a preference

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, save, boolean

I currently have an application that currently takes data from a website and stores it into a string such as "7.0.1" and then compares it to a local string of "7.1". If the strings don't match there is a notification that says there is an update available. My question is what if someone says "hide notification" as one of the options the update will not appear again... I was thinking of trying to save a boolean value and if it is set to TRUE or YES the notification appears and if a saved value is set to NO the alert is visible. However I have no idea how to set the boolean value based on a saved preference.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInteger

```
+(void)setBoolean:(BOOL)enable {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:enable forKey:@"keyforboolean"];
}

+(BOOL)getBoolean {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"keyforboolean"];
}
```

Comment: Why not `setBool:forKey`?